# Flask GET request doesn't load the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, get, recaptcha

Good evening. I am trying to stop a user from coming onto my site with reCaptcha v3. However, the template to do this is not loading, despite my debug logs showing that a GET request was sent and the page was found:

**relevent bits of routes.py**

```
from flask import url_for, render_template, redirect, request, render_template_string
from flask import current_app as app
from .forms import *
from .filewriter import *
from .mailserver import *
from .rcvalidator import *
from flask_jsglue import JSGlue

jsglue = JSGlue(app)

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def home():
    reqform = ReqForm()
    delform = DelForm()
    error = 0
    if request.method == "POST":
        gtoken = request.json['gtoken']
        if not rc_form_valid(gtoken):
            print("working")
            return redirect(url_for('inv'))
    return render_template('home.html',
                           reqform=reqform,
                           delform=delform,
                           csrf_token=0,
                           errors=error)

@app.route('/invalid')
def inv():
    print("loaded inv")
    return render_template_string("get out now")
```

Both "working" and "loaded inv" are printed. In my layout.py, an ajax JSON post is made to the server to give the RC token:

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>
    {{ JSGlue.include() }}
    {% include 'meta.html' %}
    {% block styles %}{% endblock %}
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e3deaeba31.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LeRCuMUAAAAAEWkxJ1IsbM4h-RQbGuxDxCXmdtr"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,500" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>

      var csrftoken = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')

      $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type)) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
            }
          }
      })

      grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('secret token is here', {action: 'homepage'})
        .then(function(token) {
          //appending the token to the end of the form so that the thing can go in and submit the token in the background and find the number
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: Flask.url_for("home"),
            data: JSON.stringify({"gtoken":token}),
            })
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="{{template}}">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {% block javascript %}{% endblock javascript %}
  </body>

</html>
```

meta.html provides relevant variables.

**Logs:**

```
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 502-140-539
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Mar/2020 16:21:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Mar/2020 16:21:02] "GET /jsglue.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'success': True, 'action': 'homepage', 'hostname': 'localhost', 'score': 0.9, 'challenge_ts': 'xxxxx'}
working
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Mar/2020 16:21:03] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
loaded inv
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Mar/2020 16:21:03] "GET /invalid HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The logs end here, and the page is the same. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working after soooo long. Because of the asynchronous nature of AJAX, redirects do not load after you make an AJAX call. What you have to do is add a success line into the AJAX JSON post, which says

`success: function(response) {window.location.href = response.redirect}`

then, in flask, when you're handling the request in a function, you just return a JSON with the attribute redirect:

`return jsonify({'redirect': url_for("success")})`

Answer (score 0):

If you access your website with GET request, the condition `if method == 'POST'` is false, all commands under if are ignored. The next command is to render the template 'home.html' which is observed.

Perhaps, you want to redirect to your website after the client sent POST request and it is validated?

```
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def home():
    reqform = ReqForm()
    delform = DelForm()
    error = 0
    if request.method == "POST":
        gtoken = request.json['gtoken']
        if not rc_form_valid(gtoken):
            print("working")
            return redirect(url_for('inv'))
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('main_website'))

    return render_template('home.html',
                           reqform=reqform,
                           delform=delform,
                           csrf_token=0,
                           errors=error)
```

Comment: I tried a method similar to this (as home.html is my main page) by rendering the layout.html and loading home.html on confirmation and invalid on failure. Neither ends up loading, and the site just stays on the layout.html, even though a GET for invalid still comes in

Comment: I don't know why the page is not loading... Did you try using curl to see full data you receive?

Comment: In my mind, the structure is like that:

1. Access layout.html with GET request. User see CAPTCHA, fills it out and the POST request is sent to 'layout.html'
2. layout.html gets POST request. If validated, redirect to home.html, if not, redirect to 'invalid.html'

Basically, there are two different exits from layout.html, but I see only 1 in the code. If request is validated, user sees the same CAPTCHA page.

Comment: I'm sorry - could you direct me to a guide on how curl could be used here? Also, that structure is the basic gist of it, it just seems to not work.